# Mule ESB - How to process a JSON request from a Webpage in a Java Component

Tags: java, ajax, json, mule, esb

I'm trying really hard to build the following scenario in Mule ESB 3:
1 - Send a Ajax request sending a JSON object to an AJAX endpoint in Mule ESB
2 - Map this JSON in a Java POJO using Json "Object to Json" component
3 - Invoke a Java method passing this converted object

I searched a lot of pages, but none has such a scenario. All the references doesn't have a complete example.

I know it's a very simple scenario, but its really, really hard to make such a dumb thing work in Mule ESB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mule has JSON-to-Object transformer which can be used to get JSON elements.
So, when you receive a JSON input in your flow, you extract it using JSON-to-Object transformer and using return class as  `java.lang.Object` or `java.util.List` or `java.util.HashMap` depending on your JSON.

For example if your JSON is following :-

```
{
  "token" : 123,
  "id" : 456,
  "email" : "abc@abc.com",
  "status" : "Success"
}
```

Now, to extract the elements, you need to use :-

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object" />
```

And then can extract like :- `#[message.payload.email]` or `#[message.payload.status]`

Answer (score 1):

Create a flow with an inbound HTTP endpoint, then a JSON to object transformer (not the other way around as you said) then either a component or invoke message processor, depending on how your Java object is designed.